# Best method for using Subclipse with an SSH Remote Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, ssh, subclipse

I have a Remote Project (via SSH) set up in Eclipse.

The Subclipse plugin can't utilize the Remote Project's file system:

[Subclipse forum post](http://svn.haxx.se/subusers/archive-2009-04/0027.shtml)

As a result, you can't use the Subclipse features in a Remote Project.

**Are these my only options for synchronizing a remote SSH folder in Eclipse?:**

1. rsync / Unison to a local folder with Subclipse.
2. Distributed Revision Control System.

It appears that the support for DRCS's in Eclipse is still in it's early stages and a bit shaky.

Thanks for the help,

Derek

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a local development environment in conjunction with an integration environment. Synchronizing a local folder with a remote folder turned out to be too fragile and difficult.

The development environment and integration environment require a fair amount of setup and co-ordination. Ultimately though, it is worth the effort to have a proper development, integration and production environment work flow set up.